# LWC drop down functionality with two buttons alignment issue. Want to know the reason of alignment mismatch?

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-service-cloud

I am trying to write code which shows a drop down and two buttons.

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId" >
  <aura:attribute name="carTypes" type="String[]" default="Sport Car, Luxury Car, Van"/>
  <aura:attribute name="searchbuttonlabel" type="String" default="Search"></aura:attribute>
  <aura:attribute name="newbuttonlabel" type="String" default="New Button"></aura:attribute>
    <lightning:layout horizontalAlign="center">
         <lightning:layoutItem padding ="around-medium">
              <lightning:select name="selectItem" aura:id="carType" label="Select Type of Car" variant="label-hidden" value=" " >
                <option value="" text="Select Type of Car"></option>
                <aura:iteration items="{!v.carTypes}" var="carType">
                       <option text="{!carType}"></option>
                </aura:iteration>                                
            </lightning:select>
        </lightning:layoutItem>
        
        <lightning:layoutItem padding ="around-medium">
            <lightning:button label="{!v.searchbuttonlabel}" variant="Brand"/>
            <lightning:button label="{!v.newbuttonlabel}" variant="Neutral"/>
        </lightning:layoutItem>                    
    </lightning:layout>        
</aura:component>
```

Expected output: drop-down list and two buttons to be present in center and in same line

Actual output: drop-down list and two buttons are there in center but not in same line

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the fields apper unaligned is that, even if you use the "label-hidden" variant for the lightning:select, the space that is reserved for the label is still there, so it pushes the select down. So it is "top" aligned with the buttons if you consider the empty label ocupying that space.

Some options that you could use for achieving your goal are:

1. Use a 'verticalAlign="end"' on the lightning:layout so the bottom part of the select (the actual box) is aligned with the buttons (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:layout/specification)

   ```
   <lightning:layout horizontalAlign="center" verticalAlign="end">
   ```
2. Use a .css file for the component where you are including your select and override the class that the label is using to change it's display type as mentioned in other threads (https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/160897/is-it-possible-to-remove-the-label-on-lightningnamespace-components) (https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/164804/how-to-avoid-label-in-lightning/202992). Keep in mind that this last option will also affect the other inputs in the component so it would be better to encapsulate the lightning:select in a specific component in this case.

   ```
   .THIS .slds-form-element__label {
         display : none !important;
   }
   ```